# Passing String to Fragment

Tags: android, webview, fragment, android-view

I have an EditText view in my MainActivity that the user can input a url. This MainActivity also contains a fragment which will hold a WebView.

I have it set up so that when the fragment is displayed the url will load in the WebView. However I don't know how I can pass the String to the Fragment?

Below is the Main Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

Button goBtn;
EditText urlInput;
String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    goBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    urlInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    goBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            url = "http://"+urlInput.getText().toString(); //THIS TO FRAGMENT!

            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Search:" + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and this is the fragment code:

```
    WebView webDisplay;
String url;
AsyncHttpClient client;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);
    urlDisplay = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    webDisplay = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //url = "http://"+this.getActivity() ???
    client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            webDisplay.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                          view.loadUrl(url);
                          return true;
                }}); 
            webDisplay.loadUrl(url);
        }
    });
```

The value I am concerned about it the String URL variable in MainActivity.java.

The transaction of the fragments is controlled by a class TabFragment.

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

private static final int TAB1_STATE = 0x1;
private static final int TAB2_STATE = 0x2;
private int mTabState;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);
    //References to buttons in layout file
    Button tabBtn1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.tabBtn1);
    Button tabBtn2 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.tabBtn2);

    //add listener to buttons
    tabBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Action to perform when Tab 1 clicked...
            goToTab1View();

        }
    });

    tabBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Action to perform when Tab 2 clicked...
            goToTab2View();
        }
    });

    return v;

}

//Tab action functions.
protected void goToTab1View() {
    if(mTabState != TAB1_STATE){
        mTabState = TAB1_STATE;
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if(fm!= null){
            //Perform fragment transaction
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, new FragTab1());
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}

protected void goToTab2View() {
    if(mTabState != TAB2_STATE){
        mTabState = TAB2_STATE;
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if(fm!= null){
            //Perform fragment transaction
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, new FragTab2());
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is in case the fragment already exists

You can define a public method in your fragment. Something like:

```
public void setString(final String str) { //... }
```

After that make your activity to implement OnClickListener interfave. And when the button is pressed just type something like that:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
// Form url...
((YourWebViewFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragments_id)).setString(url);
}
```

Comment: I am trying your suggestion but now I am getting a nullpointerexception error.

Comment: Is your fragment attached? An NPE usualy means that `findFragmentById()` returns null.

Comment: When you say is the fragment attached do you mean is it in the container prior to me doing what you said above? If you do then it is not, when the activity starts there is just two tabs with no content.

Comment: Then you should use Nikola Despotoski suggestion, because `getFraagmentById(id)` returns null if there is no fragment attached. If you need some help with that I can explain how to use his approach.

Comment: I actually managed to get it working with your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Or create `Bundle` and set it using method `fragment.setArguments(myBundle);`

Comment: This is done before you call `commit()` on `FragmentTransaction`